# How can I force Hadoop to use my hostnames instead of IP-XX-XX-XX-XX

Tags: hadoop, configuration

So, I'm configuring a 10 node cluster with Hadoop 2.5.2, and so far it's working, but the only issue I have is that when trying to communicate with the nodes, Hadoop is guessing their hostnames based on their IP, instead of using the ones I've configured.

Let me be more specific: this is happening when starting a job, but when I start up yarn (for instance), the slave nodes names, are used correctly. The scheme that Hadoop uses to auto-generate the names of the nodes is IP-XX-XX-XX-XX, so for a node with IP 179.30.0.1 it's name would be IP-179-30-0-1.

This is forcing me to edit every /etc/hosts file on each node, so that their 127.0.0.1 ip is named like Hadoop says.

Can I make Hadoop use the names I have those hosts? Or am I force to do this extra configuration step normally?

Comment: If the IP and hostnames of every machines are properly mapped in the dhcp. Hadoop will also use the correct hostname. If not, you have to make the corresponding changes in /etc/hosts of every machines and use the hostnames in hadoop configurations instead of ip address.

Comment: Interesting, this is a AWS cluster, where would I configure the DHCP (sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm a bit of a beginner with these types of things)

Comment: In case of AWS, you don't need to worry about DHCP. In aws ec2 machines, if you enabled public dns, each machine will have 2 ip address and 2 hostnames (Private and Public). The private hostname will be in a format ip-x-x-x-x and public hostname will be ec2-xxx-xxx.compute.amazonaws.com.

Comment: Ok, so that's why hadoop is using that hostname, it's using the private hostname. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!